# Testing multiple implementations of an interface in a single test class

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit.net

I need to pass test data on class level but `Theory` and `InlineData` attributes can only be used on methods.

```
public class ContainerTests : TestFixture
{
    private IContainer _container;

    public ContainerTests(string containerName)
    {
        _container = CreateContainer(containerName);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ResolveJobFactory()
    {
        IJobFactory jobFactory = _container.Resolve<IJobFactory>();
    }

    private IContainer CreateContainer(string containerName)
    {
        if (containerName == "CastleWindsor")
        {
            return new WindsorContainerAdapter();
        }
        //other adapters

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve something similar in xUnit.net?

Comment: See http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/09/GenericunittestingwithxUnit.net/ (And I'm certain thsi is a dup question, it's jsut not popping out)

Comment: Thanks @RubenBartelink . Just using inheritance solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Testing multiple implementations of an interface in a single test
>   class

Don't! Have a test class per implementation.

Edit: As per comments, I recommend having a base TestClass with all of the common tests, and then a Test Class per implementation which inherits from this base class.

Comment: Thanks but this is not an answer really.  I am expecting the same behaviour from all of the implementations. Can you explain why that's a bad idea?

Comment: So that I understand your problem, what are you trying to test exactly? Do you have several implementations of IJobFactory and you you want to test they all behave in a certain way? Or is it that you have 1 implementation of IJobFactory, but you just want to test that all the containers are building it correctly?

Comment: If it's the former, then you could write a base test class that has all your tests against an implementation of IJobFactory. You would then write a test class which inherited from this base for each implementation of IJobFactory. Each inheritor would simply be responsible for building the implementation of IJobFactory, and then the base class would do the rest of the work.

Comment: Thanks. That's how I did it in the end. Could you put your comment in the answer? It will be easier for other people to find it.