# How to mock an interface with multiple implementation?

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I have an interface which is implemented by two classes.

```
public IMyInterface
{
 void DoSomething();
}


public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    internal readonly SomeParameter p;
    public MyBaseClass (SomeParameter p)
    {
        this.p = p;
    }
}


public class Foo : MyBaseClass, IMyInterface
{
    public Foo (SomeParameter p) : base(SomeParameter p)
    {

    }
}


public class Bar : MyBaseClass, IMyInterface
{
    public Bar (SomeParameter p) : base(SomeParameter p)
    {

    }
}
```

Now how should I test `DoSomething()` method implemented in `Foo` class using Moq?

@Nkosi
I want to do something like following.

```
public class FooTest
{
   [Fact]
    public void DoSomethingTest()
    {
         //Arrange
         //Here I'm facing problem to get a mock for Foo class. 
         //Mock of IMyInterface must be Foo here.
          var foo = new Mock<IMyInterface>();

         //Act
         //Another problem: Here DoSomething is not getting called.
         foo.DoSomething();             

         //Assert
         
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show more details. The question in it's current state is incomplete and that make it unclear what you want and also impossible for us to properly understand the problem and provide you with a solution.

Comment: No where have you shown the implementation of `DoSomething` so there is no way to tell if MOQ is even needed in the requested scenario

Comment: This might be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I can see you are using XUnit and there is already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286353/testing-multiple-implementations-of-an-interface-in-a-single-test-class) about basically the same thing. tl;dr - don't do it, just have two test classes

Comment: No need to mock the subject under test. Mock the explicit dependencies injected into an actual instance of the subject under test when exercising the test case

Comment: @Quacke, Didn't get you. This `FooTest` is for `Foo` class, there will be a `BarTest` is for `Bar` class.

Comment: Okay, I didn't get you there, I think I see what the issue is now tho, posting an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are confused as to what the mock objects are meant to do. You **do not** mock the class you are testing. Mocks are meant to replace dependencies for the classes you test (Like the `p` constructor parameter in your example). To test the class you instantiate the actual class you want to test, so:

```
public class FooTest
{
   [Fact]
    public void DoSomethingTest()
    {
         //Arrange
         var p = new Mock<SomeParameter>();
         var foo = new Foo(p.Object);

         //Act
         foo.DoSomething();             

         //Assert
         
    }
}
```